# C# Linq SQL save List<Point>

Tags: sql, linq

I have a class Point:

```
class Point
{
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

and class Chart which aggregates cca 1000 points.

```
[Table(Name = "Chart")] 
class Chart
{
  public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
}
```

I want to efficiently save Points to database. I don't need to do any operation on top of Points. Is there a way how to save the points in a single column? I think this way should be more efficient than creating new Table for 1000000 points. Thx

Comment: you mean new rows? I don't see more efficent ways, it's kind of the point of databases

Answer (score 1):

Look up `SqlBulkCopy` - it's not Linq, but it allows you to push masses of data into SQL Server much more quickly than Linq would.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a table. 1000000 rows of two ints, a double and an FK is a going to be pretty darn efficient. If you're worried about getting the data to and from the database perhaps doing something other than linq to sql is required for this data

That said you *could* use an [XML type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510446.aspx) column and store your points in there, which is supported by Linq to sql. But not without some other considerations.

[From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx)

> The SQL Server XML data type is
>   available starting in Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2005. You can map the SQL
>   Server XML data type to XElement,
>   XDocument, or String. If the column
>   stores XML fragments that cannot be
>   read into XElement, the column must be
>   mapped to String to avoid run-time
>   errors. XML fragments that must be
>   mapped to String include the
>   following:
>
> A sequence of XML elements
>
> Attributes
>
> Public Identifiers (PI)
>
> Comments
>
> Although you can map XElement and
>   XDocument to SQL Server as shown in
>   the Type Mapping Run Time Behavior
>   Matrix, the DataContext.CreateDatabase
>   method has no default SQL Server type
>   mapping for these types.